# jquery html function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

The container which outputs the "Loading.." isn't working even if its taking 2 seconds to load the page.
but if I put "alert" after the html function I am able to see the "Loading.."
How can I fix that?

```
function loadURL(url, container) {
    //console.log(container)



    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : url, 
        data: 'ajax=1',// Dan Revah: Added ajax parameter to url
        dataType : 'html',
        cache : true, // (warning: this will cause a timestamp and will call the request twice)
        beforeSend : function() {
            // cog placed
    container.html('<h1><i class="fa fa-cog fa-spin"></i> Loading...</h1>');

            if (container[0] == $("#content")[0]) {
                drawBreadCrumb();
                // update title with breadcrumb...
                document.title = $(".breadcrumb li:last-child").text();
                // scroll up
                $("html, body").animate({
                    scrollTop : 0
                }, "fast");
            } else {
                container.animate({
                    scrollTop : 0
                }, "fast");
            }
        },
        /*complete: function(){
            // Handle the complete event
            // alert("complete")
        },*/
        success : function(data) {
            // cog replaced here...
            // alert("success")

            container.css({
                opacity : '0.0'
            }).html(data).delay(50).animate({
                opacity : '1.0'
            }, 300);


        },
        error : function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            container.html('<h4 style="margin-top:10px; display:block; text-align:left"><i class="fa fa-warning txt-color-orangeDark"></i> Error 404! Page not found.</h4>');
        },
        async : false
    });

    //console.log("ajax request sent");
}
```

Edit:
Container in my code is

```
container = $('#content');
```

Edit: 
I've just noticed that it works in Firefox. the problem is Chrome.

Comment: Maype put the Javascripts in de bottom of your page..

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe you need to wrap container variable like this:$(container).html("Loading")?

Comment: To make call not asynchronous add async:false

Comment: What is `container` in your code?

Comment: Is your content just loading to quickly so you dont see your loading message. This is prob why your alert means you see it.

Comment: @DinRevah Can you create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to show us what is exactly wrong?

Comment: I've just noticed its working in firefox the problem is Chrome!

Comment: Sure this is not some cache issue? Sounds very, very strange, a fiddle would help a lot.